# Check if a given array contains a subsequence of elements

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to check if a given array contains a given subsequence.

E.g. { 1, 4, **4, 0, 4**, 2 } contains the "subarray" {**4, 0, 4**}, so this means the sequence that is formed by the elements of the subarray (in this case the subsequence is 4, 0, 4) should appear (in that particular order of course) in the given array. It clearly does in the example I gave.

My try:

```
bool isSubArray(int firstArr[], int secondArr[], int fSize, int sSize)
{
    //int arr1[6] = { 1, 4, 4, 0, 4, 2 };
    //int subarr[3] = { 4, 0, 4 };
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    bool isSubArray = false;
    while (i < fSize)
    {
        cout << "i before the if = " << i << endl;
        cout << "j before the if = " << j << endl;
        if (firstArr[i++] != secondArr[j])
        {
            j = 0;
        }
        else j++;
        cout << "i after the if = " << i << endl;
        cout << "j after the if = " << j << endl;

        if (j == fSize - 1)
        {
            isSubArray = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isSubArray;
}
```

I think my idea is clear, but it doesn't seem to work. I think I've figured out why. When we compare `firstArr[1]` with `secondArr[0]`, they're equal, so `j` is now `1`, then we compare `firstArr[2]` with `secondArr[1]`, they're not equal, so on the next iteratation we'll compare `firstArr[3]` with `secondArr[0]`, and we'll actually miss the subsequence. I figured out why it does not work, but how do I fix it now? I can't come up with a way. Thanks!

Comment: Should `{ 1, 4, 14, 0, 4, 2 }` return `true` if we wish to search for `4, 0, 4`?

Comment: @nice_dev, nope.

Comment: Ok, so we have to strictly look for a subarray inside and not a subsequence, right? Because the wording in your question has subsequence and not a subarray.

Comment: Think of this as 2 loops: one over all the places where the subarray could start, and for each of these, one to check to see if the subarray actually is there.

Comment: When you set `j = 0;`, you can always decrease `i` as well: `i--;` (with the caveat of `i` not going lower than 0). Alternatively, replace the `[i++]` with `[i]` and put the `i++;` in the else clause together with `j++`. Although both these solutions will only look one element back, while you may have to look back more elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are these issues:

- You compare `j` with `fSize - 1`, but they are unrelated. `j` is an index in the second array, so the comparison should be with `sSize`. Also, because `j` has been increased after the most recent equivalence, you should not have that `- 1`.
- When there is a difference, it is not enough to set `j` to 0. This is because it might be that the match in the first array will still start earlier than the current `i`. So `i` should be reduced. More precisely, `i` should return to what it was when the *first* entries matched, and increase with one step from there.

Not a problem, but:

- you don't really need the `isSubArray` variable. Just replace by `break` by `return true`, and the fall-thru should do `return false`.
- you could exit the loop when it is clear that there aren't enough entries anymore in the first array for a complete match.

So your code corrected:

```cpp
bool isSubArray(int firstArr[], int secondArr[], int fSize, int sSize)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (sSize - j <= fSize - i) // Enough room for a match
    {
        if (firstArr[i] != secondArr[j]) {
            i -= j - 1; // reset to the start of the match, plus one step
            j = 0;
        } else {
            i++;
            j++;
            if (j == sSize)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

But it seems easier to use two loops, where `i` remains locked to the start of the match:

```cpp
bool isSubArray(int firstArr[], int secondArr[], int fSize, int sSize)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i <= fSize - sSize; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < sSize && firstArr[i+j] == secondArr[j]; j++) {}
        if (j >= sSize) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that this is still a quite naive algorithm. It is possible to get better efficiency. See [Wikipedia - String-searching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm#Examples_of_search_algorithms) for some more efficient algorithms, including the KMP and Boyer–Moore algorithms.